# getting linux booted

Tags: linux, system-installation, bios

I just bought a new notebook without os and was trying to get linux going. So I burned the linux ubuntu iso from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop on a dvd and set up my bios menu to boot from dvd. However when I start the pc, he just refuses to boot from my dvd. So I tried to do the same thing with a win on a different dvd and it worked just fine. I tried to figure out what I am doing wrong for several hours now. 
Its a lenovo notebook with freeos installed. bios settings are booted from legacy and ofc dvd.

Comment: What MODEL of Lenovo notebook?

Comment: https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/notebooks/lenovo+v110+15isk+80tl00ahge this one.

Comment: by the way, I am not 100% sure how it is suppost to work, the win DVD is a unziped iso version. I tried it with ubuntu with the iso on the dvd only and with the unziped folders, still none will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, my answer could be too helpfull: I solved something similar with Lenovo ThinkPad, but there was MS-windows8 preinstalled. It was necessary to toggle many settings in BIOS. Namely: the BIOS reloaded the factory default; the option "quick boot" blocked to boot anything else than WindowsBootManager; usualy there are some dirty trick under the "Secure boot" BIOS menu; if possible use "legacy" instead of UEFI. I do not have CD/DVD drive, hence I booted from USB "hybrid" - I hope, the Ubuntu Live CD ISO image can be also used on USB-flash. You can test also some other Live distributioins - Kali, CAINE, ArchLinux, Fedora, Debian etc. Cross fingers or pray.

Comment: I can only set these things in my bios->boot
boot mode: legacy support;  boot priorit: legacy first;
pxe boot to lan: disabled; usb boot: disabled; boot priority order: 1st atapi cd 2nd.....

Comment: If you make some changes, then "Save & Exit", do they remain after restart?

Comment: yes they do. I even tried a little bit of settings around, but it wont work

Comment: Try to search on the last leaf of BIOS, there have to be something like "Reload default on restart" and check it off. To describe it precisely, I must restart may notebook :-).

Comment: 1st thanks for restarting :D I have a setting called "load default settings" in the exit leaf. I tried it already and had no succes, I tried the os optimized defaults as well

Comment: With my experiments I totaly knocked out my notebook, hence I should response from my work. Some choices on the last leaf react immediately (eg. load default settings). But there must be something I suddenly could not find, what prevent the boot actions to be changed - because anything what you change in the boot and secure menus is forgotten on restart.

Comment: You need to bypass the WindowsBootManager (which alows the Windows Installation Media, too) and reach to the F12 - "choose the boot device" on the restart.

Comment: There is a freedos installed. When I restart I get the freedos startingscreen no matter what I do. I tried f12 and selected DVD, but he just loads the freedos again. As I already mentioned, I tried with an iso file on the dvd only and even with the unziped iso version. I am not sure what is suppost to work, but one of it should.

Comment: I found this link in my archive: 
<<support.lenovo.com/cz/en/solutions/ht076905>>
You can see, it is not simple, so good luck.